# Bootstrap Carousel Chrome laptop issues

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

We've been working on a slideshow using Bootstrap Carousel. Works well in most places, except Chrome on a laptop (Macbook). We've tested it on desktop computers using Chrome, where it renders fine (even at narrower widths).

I didn't see any errors in Console either:
http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/time-line-test.php

I get very odd errors:
thing disappear on rollover, controls don't work, it looks like images are not completely loading, it starts on the wrong slide-- but only on a laptop. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider using [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2F69.195.124.96%2F~scottar4%2Ftime-line-test.php&tab=mobile) to fix the most common problems. It your current issues are related to resources taking too long to load or timing out, PSI suggestions will probably help you fix them. One problem I noticed and PSI won't is you are using a `1920px x 354px` animated gif image while the animated area is `~60px x 60px` and most of it is transparent. Use [centering](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/299/centering#t=201704202055075787214)!

Comment: Another huge problem is you are loading ***150 images***, some of them quite large. Consider lazy loading. If you don't want/know how to code it yourself, use a plugin that lazy loads (most sliders do). Most traffic these days is mobile. People will look at 10, maybe 20 of the 150 images. It makes no sense to load them all. Even if you have to load them all, your're only displaying 2-3 on a screen at any one time. Render the page when you have ATF content and load more as the user asks for more. Your page is a nightmare for mobile users, especially on 3G.